# Open utility item in modal only, not in standard utility panel mode

Tags: lightning-aura-components, utility-bar

I have a requirement where I need to display utility item in a modal window only.

I have also embedded an aura component inside the utility item.

So whenever user clicks on the utility item header, it should not open the standard utility panel,

instead it should immediately open the component in modal window.

I have already tried a lot of alternatives but it's not working.

Tried below approach as well, but it's not working satisfactorily.
Standard utility panel is opening in all the case(s).

How to display only modal, keeping the standard utility panel in minimize mode ?

```
<aura:component implements="flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes" access="global">
    <lightning:utilityBarAPI aura:id="utilitybar" />
    <lightning:button label="Register Event Handler" onclick="{!c.registerUtilityClickHandler}"/>
</aura:component>
```

---

```
    ({
    registerUtilityClickHandler: function(component, event, helper){
        var utilityBarAPI = component.find("utilitybar");
        var eventHandler = function(response){
            console.log(response);
        };

        utilityBarAPI.onUtilityClick({
            eventHandler: eventHandler
        }).then(function(result){
            console.log(result);
        }).catch(function(error){
            console.log(error);
        });
    }
})
```

Please help here.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use [lightning:overlay](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:overlayLibrary/documentation)

You can use the UtilityBarApi to close the Utility Bar once it's open -

You can check if the bar is open or not -

```
var utilityAPI = component.find("UtilityBarEx");
utilityAPI.openUtility().then(function (utilityId
console.log('open ',utilityId);
}
```

You can close the bar using the -

```
var utilityAPI = component.find("UtilityBarEx");
utilityAPI.minimizeUtility();
```

Comment: Thank you for prompt response, but I think with lightning:overlay also, we will have to first open the utility in minimize mode, then clicking on the button to open the modal.

But In our scenario we want to just show the modal don't even want to open the utility item.

Is it possible at the same time ? Please suggest.

Comment: Please check the updated answer

Comment: Can we prevent the opening of utility item, if possible ?

So that On clicking of utility item, component should be displayed in modal window
without opening the utility item.

Comment: I don;t think so it's possible you can minimize the bar whenever the user opens it

Comment: Thank you for the confirmation.

Comment: @ParvindraSingh try setting height as `0`, so that the utility bar just works as buttion and does not really open up

Comment: @NagendraSingh  I've tried that but it's not working actually.
Clicking on the utility item is not opening any popup.

Comment: @ParvindraSingh, you need to close the modal pop-up using the code I have shared, try running that code in the aura rerender file.https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/js_renderers.htm